# How to run two commands in npm scripts if first command start a server?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

For example, I want to run two commands by npm scripts, the first command starts a node server. I find that the first command executed success but the first command stops the second command to execute.How can I do to execute these two commands successfully?

### package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www & gulp dev"
  }
```

> nodemon ./bin/www starts a node server and the gulp dev does not execute.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `&` to say *run this command **&** this command*

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "commandA --arguments whatever & commandB params --arguments"
}
```